# Nginx stops responding after a while. Possible pagespeed fault?

Tags: nginx, page-speed

If anyone could please help me out with this issue, I'd be VERY grateful!

Running EasyEngine with nginx/1.8.0 and PageSpeed 1.9.32.4-7251. Almost every day, after a certain time I assume, the website stops responding and I have to restart the nginx service remotely. Monit doesn't catch the fault.
I think this excerpt from `error.log` is connected.

What could be causing the problem? How can I remedy this?

```
2015/12/28 06:35:17 [info] 28791#0: [ngx_pagespeed 1.9.32.4-7251] No threading detected. Own threads: 1 Rewrite, 1 Expensive Rewrite.
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *0 open socket #19 left in connection 4
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *50008 open socket #3 left in connection 5
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *50009 open socket #28 left in connection 6
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *50010 open socket #31 left in connection 7
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *0 open socket #29 left in connection 8
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *0 open socket #32 left in connection 9
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *50011 open socket #34 left in connection 10
....
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *0 open socket #822 left in connection 536
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *50298 open socket #824 left in connection 537
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *0 open socket #825 left in connection 538
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *50299 open socket #827 left in connection 539
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *0 open socket #828 left in connection 540
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *50300 open socket #830 left in connection 541
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *0 open socket #831 left in connection 542
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *50301 open socket #833 left in connection 543
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *0 open socket #834 left in connection 544
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *50302 open socket #836 left in connection 545
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *0 open socket #837 left in connection 546
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *50303 open socket #839 left in connection 547
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *0 open socket #840 left in connection 548
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *50304 open socket #842 left in connection 549
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *0 open socket #843 left in connection 550
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *50305 open socket #845 left in connection 551
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *0 open socket #846 left in connection 552
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *50306 open socket #848 left in connection 553
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *0 open socket #849 left in connection 554
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *50307 open socket #851 left in connection 555
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *0 open socket #852 left in connection 556
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *50308 open socket #854 left in connection 557
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: *0 open socket #855 left in connection 558
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: aborting
2015/12/28 06:35:18 [alert] 30740#0: [ngx_pagespeed 1.9.32.4-7251] [1228/063519:FATAL:categorized_refcount.h(118)] Check failed: ref_counts_[category] >= 0 (-1 vs. 0)0
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x551419]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x54e432]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x5a6333]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x58e22c]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x58e35d]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x61ca27]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x57c200]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x69e04e]
nginx: worker process is shutting down(net_instaweb::NgxRewriteDriverFactory::~NgxRewriteDriverFactory()+0x1b) [0x516c8b]
nginx: worker process is shutting down(net_instaweb::NgxRewriteDriverFactory::~NgxRewriteDriverFactory()+0x9) [0x516e09]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x50dee6]
nginx: worker process is shutting down(ngx_destroy_pool+0x1e) [0x42b14e]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x44a39b]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x44a54a]
nginx: worker process is shutting down(ngx_spawn_process+0x170) [0x448ec0]
nginx: worker process is shutting down(ngx_master_process_cycle+0x716) [0x44b986]
nginx: worker process is shutting down(main+0x77f) [0x428d0f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f400f1eaec5]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x4292cf]

nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x551419]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x508810]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x54e514]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x5a6333]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x58e22c]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x58e35d]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x61ca27]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x57c200]
nginx: worker process is shutting down() [0x69e04e]
nginx: worker process is shutting down(net_instaweb::NgxRewriteDriverFactory::~NgxRewriteDriverFactory()+0x1b) [0x516c8b]
nginx: worker process is shutting down(net_instaweb::Ngx
```

Comment: That one's pretty obviously the pagespeed module misbehaving.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well, yes, but I'm interested in what exactly causes it. I'd rather not just disable PageSpeed completely.

Comment: OK, have you filed a bug report?